# String addition with an another string contains "+"

Tags: java, string

I have 2 strings

```
String date = "23:02:2007";
String offset = "+08:00";
```

When we add this like

```
String dO = date+offset;
syso("dO: "+dO);
```

We are expecting the result should be `dO: 23:02:2007+08:00`;
I am getting the above result when i am trying this in my local eclipse. But when it is deployed to our dev server, then we are getting this response like

```
dO: 23:02:2007 08:00;
```

`"+"` is missing and instead a `" "` is getting added. Please help me on this

Comment: Have you tried printing offset alone on the dev server?

Comment: We have no idea what is happening with that string - whether this is seen in a log or something else. Please provide a lot more information, and ideally a [mcve].

Comment: that code is working fine by me!!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to encoding and decoding of the character '+'.
In services like Jersey the plus symbol is automatically decoded to space. Also in case of URLs the plus symbol is decoded as space (you can solve this by replacing it with %2B).

This also happens within a request send to a servlet. For that any parameters with plus symbol has to be URL-Encoded before sending. If you could let us know the context you're using this string, then we could provide an accurate solution.

Comment: Thanks Vijayan, My input is in xml format and im getting this like <Cd>startTime</Cd>
                        <Val Ty="DATETIME">2017-02-23T12:30Z</Val>,    <Cd>Offset</Cd>
                        <Val Ty="CHAR">+8:00</Val>. After parsing this i will get Strings StartTime and Offset. But after parsing this "+" from offset is replaced with " ". Could you please help me how retain the original string as in the request,

Comment: The '+' sign is considered a special character in XML encoding and it gets replaced with space(UTF-8 encoding). This is a default encoding mechanism and changing this encoding is not advisable. Considering the usage - this is impacting only one occurrence; so we can use replace() method to change space into plus sign for this instance. Normally, this decoding is used for URLs with URLDecoder method in java; but that is not applicable in this case.